# Why does the background image scale with this markup?

Tags: css

My style definition is:

```
<style>
  .x { background-image:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/sheet_emojione_64.png); 
       border:solid 1px red; 
     }
</style>
```

The [image file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamcal/emoji-data/master/sheet_emojione_64.png) above is 2624px x 2624px containing emojis in 64px square cells.  64 is 1/41 of 2624.  The image in cell 13,7 is a camel.

My markup is:

```
<div class='x' style='background-position:-832px -448px; height:64px; width:64px;' ></div>
<div class='x' style='background-position:-832px -448px; background-size:4100%; 
   height:64px; width:64px;' ></div>
<div class='x' style='background-position:-312px -168px; background-size:4100%; 
   height:24px; width:24px;' ></div>
```

The JS Fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/5j5ahhda/ and the output is:

[image]

My understanding of the second `DIV` is that I am squeezing a 2624px image into a 64px square, 1/41th of its size, and then blowing it up 41 times, thus resulting in an image the same as the original size. Is this understanding correct?

The third `DIV` produces what I was setting out to achieve, but I don't understand what causes the background image to scale nicely to 24/64.  Is it the specified size of the containing `DIV` that causes the scaling?

What I want is 24/64 of the original image size. Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: why you want to extend the background-size to 4100%? the size is the width and hight of the div.

Comment: If I don't scale, the background image is in its original size and that's not what I want.  I want the background to be 24/64 of the original image file.

Comment: background-size:4100% means 4100% of the divs dimensions...not of the imgs dimensions.

Comment: If you want the background to be 24/64 of its original size, and the size is 2624x2624 pixels, then the command to do so is, ahem, `background-size:984px 984px;`

Comment: @MihaiT That explains it! Thanks.

Comment: Why not use background-size:cover and be done with it?

Comment: @scooterlord: Probably because the intention is *not* to display the entire sprite map in a single element, but specific sprites?

Comment: The last paragraph of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding of the second `DIV` is that I am squeezing a 2624px image into a 64px square, 1/41th of its size, and then blowing it up 41 times, thus resulting in an image the same as the original size. Is this understanding correct?

Yes.

> The third `DIV` produces what I was setting out to achieve, but I don't understand what causes the background image to scale nicely to 24/64. Is it the specified size of the containing `DIV` that causes the scaling?

Yes. A percentage `background-size` is [relative to the size of the element's background positioning area](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size). This area is determined by the element's dimensions, not the image's. This is what allows a background image to scale with the size of the element based on the element's dimensions when a percentage `background-size` is set.